# Properly set up React SSR with Parcel and Express

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering, parceljs

I have read lots of tutorials and looked at some repositories and still didn't get what I wanted.

For example, [this](https://github.com/reactivestack/parcel-react-ssr) repo uses Cheerio (server-like jQuery) and React Helmet.

But I want to setup my app with only Parcel, React, ReactDOM, React Router DOM and Express.

I tried to render components on a server but it isn't what I want. I want to use `hydrate` function but don't know how to make it rendering on server. server.js looked like this, but here only one  component is rendered, but not anything else:

```
import express from 'express'
import React from 'react'
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import App from '../app/index'

const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(renderToString(<App/>))
})
```

I took this from tutorials, but it only renders App, but I need lots of components to be rendered! In other words, I just need to setup React SSR with Parcel.

My NPM scripts to build the app:

```
   "build-client": "parcel app/index.html -d dist/client --port 3000",
   "build-server": "parcel server/index.js -d dist/server --target node",
   "run-server": "nodemon dist/server/index.js",
   "server": "run-s build-server run-server"
```

Will be glad to see a complete repo on how to setup React SSR without any additonal libs except Express and Parcel, but if there is any React SSR middleware plugin for express, it would be cool if someone shares it here.

Answer (score -3):

I recommend checking out [Next.js](https://nextjs.org). It is a production-ready framework built on top React & Express. It solves **SSR** out of the box with zero config.

Comment: This is not answering the question. He is actually asking how to use React SSR with Parcel. Next.js is a great tool but for some reason you might want to use other tools...